# If a new user posts a qustion do you check if it is duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I am quite new to this site. My question is what is the first thing you do when you find a Question that is posted by a new user and you know how to answer it.

Do you check if it is a 
duplicate of a all ready answered question  or do you just answer it with out checking if it is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process I use for answering questions goes something like this:

- Is it off-topic? *(Then vote to close.)*
- Does it sound familiar? *(If I've seen something similar, I will try to hunt it down.)*
- Does anything similar show up in the sidebar?

  [image]

If my answer to all of those is "no", then I don't consider any further effort to be warranted in searching for duplicates and I begin composing an answer.

Comment: This. You'll eventually develop a "feel" for if a question is a duplicate or not. If you're not sure you can always ask in [chat] too.

Comment: I usually do the same ^ what seth [suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)

Comment: In addition I often perform a Google site search (`site:askubuntu.com <searchterm>`) for finding duplicates. This often reveals much more related questions and answers with possible duplicates showing up on top of the search results.